# Plot a table with box size changing

Tags: r, plot, matlab-figure

Does anyone have an idea how is this kind of chart plotted? It seems like **heat map**. However, instead of using color, size of each cell is used to indicate the magnitude. I want to plot a figure like this but I don't know how to realize it. Can this be done in R or Matlab?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try scatter:

```
scatter(x,y,sz,c,'s','filled');
```

where x and y are the positions of each square, sz is the size (must be a vector of the same length as x and y), and c is a 3xlength(x) matrix with the color value for each entry. The labels for the plot can be input with set(gcf,*properties*) or xticklabels:

```
X=30;
Y=10;
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:X,1:Y);
x=reshape(x,[size(x,1)*size(x,2) 1]);
y=reshape(y,[size(y,1)*size(y,2) 1]);

sz=50;
sz=sz*(1+rand(size(x)));
c=[1*ones(length(x),1) repmat(rand(size(x)),[1 2])];
scatter(x,y,sz,c,'s','filled');

xlab={'ACC';'BLCA';etc}
xticks(1:X)
xticklabels(xlab)
set(get(gca,'XLabel'),'Rotation',90);
ylab={'RAPGEB6';etc}
yticks(1:Y)
yticklabels(ylab)
```

EDIT: yticks & co are only available for >R2016b, if you don't have a newer version you should use set instead:

```
set(gca,'XTick',1:X,'XTickLabel',xlab,'XTickLabelRotation',90) %rotation only available for >R2014b
set(gca,'YTick',1:Y,'YTickLabel',ylab)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide information about the packages you are using

Comment: @d.b - this is Matlab, no _packages_, just _toolboxes_, and in this case none of them is needed.

Comment: Nice. You should replace `xticks`, `xticklabels`, `yticks`, `yticklabels` with `set` or HG2 commands (i.e. `ax = gca, ax.XTick` and so on...), as this code results in an error.

Answer (score 2):

In `R`, `corrplot`package can be used. Specifically, you have to use `method = 'square'` when creating the plot.

Try this as an example:

```
library(corrplot)
corrplot(cor(mtcars), method = 'square', col = 'red')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

in R, you should use `ggplot2` that allows you to map your values (gene expression in your case?) onto the `size` variable. Here, I did a simulation that resembles your data structure:

```
my_data <- matrix(rnorm(8*26,mean=0,sd=1), nrow=8, ncol=26,
                  dimnames = list(paste0("gene",1:8), LETTERS))
```

Then, you can process the data frame to be ready for `ggplot2` data visualization:

```
library(reshape)
dat_m <- melt(my_data, varnames = c("gene", "cancer"))
```

Now, use `ggplot2::geom_tile()` to map the values onto the `size` variable. You may update additional features of the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=dat_m, aes(cancer, gene)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(size=value, fill="red"), color="white") + 
  scale_fill_discrete(guide=FALSE) + ##hide scale
  scale_size_continuous(guide=FALSE) ##hide another scale
```

[image]

Comment: Side note: If you happen to use the Tableau software (which may require a subscription or license), it appears that there are features that allow you to make the plot you want: http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/buildexamples_heatmap.html